# How to remove ',' from input

Tags: javascript

I found this code: 
`oninput="event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,'');"`

I need something like this, only number `0-9` and '.' BUT without','

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Why don't you take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think it could be useful for you and the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use another replace for delete ','

```
oninput="event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(',','');"
```

Answer (score 0):

your regular expression is almost right

```
 const test = "abc1230.,";
 console.log(test.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
```